# как избавится от проблемы в speechrecognition?

Tags: python

код:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser

def talk(words):
    print(words)
    os.system('say' + words)

talk('hi, how can i help you?')
```

ошибки нет, но выводит вот что и ничего не говорит:

```
hi, how can i help you?
"sayhi"             ७           譥 
        ,  ᯮ  塞    ணࠬ               䠩   .
```

Comment: `say` это какая-то программа, воспроизводящая текст? 1) у вас нет пробела после `say` 2) текст нужно в кавычки помещать 3) лучше использовать `subprocess`

Comment: пишет, что subprocess не найден

Comment: `subprocess` нужно импортировать, это модуль. И посмотрите методы из `subprocess`, т.к. подозреваю, что наверняка попробуйте что-то вроде `subprocess('say' + words)` и, конечно, не выйдет. Там есть разные методы, но вы можете попробовать с: `subprocess.call(["say", words], shell=True)`